# How to preserve simple HTML formatting to textbox input?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I only want to maintain the paragraph structure of the users input into a textbox. When I retrieve the text from db, all structure is lost. What's easiest way to save text as recorded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `<pre></pre>`

Answer (score 0):

replace spaces " " with `&nbsp;` You can't repeat multiple spaces " " in HTML, as they will be collapsed into one space.

Also, replace \n with <br />

Hope that helps!

Comment: Whilst this will work, it's a lot of hassle, compared to wrapping the text in a <pre></pre> element, as suggested by @Skay. You would need to consider tabs too, which is a whole new ball game.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store HTML text (rich text with BOLD , Italic and etc) you have to use an editor like CKEditor (http://www.ckeditor.com)

Comment: The question was not about entering HTML, it was about preserving and displaying the whitespace that is inherent in the text entered via a textbox (I'm presuming a <textarea> element)